# Travis (espresso tests) not running firebase calls on android

Tags: android, firebase, travis-ci, android-espresso

I need help with travis CI! It will be greatly appreciated. So I'm using android 2.3.3 and firebase as my back end. I'm running unit tests written with espresso to login when user enters email and password. I'm also using travis ci and coveralls. The test passes on my machine and on travis ci but on travis not all code is run when I check on coveralls.

Here is the login code.

```
 public void loginAccount(String email, String password){ //runs
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)  //runs
            .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() { //runs
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) { //does not run!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(home);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

The first 3 lines run but the rest does not.

Here is the test file. The email and password are already in the database and should allow the emulator to login into the app.

```
private String mStringToBetyped;
private String mNumberToBetyped;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivity = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);


@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<HomeActivity> intentsTestRule =
        new IntentsTestRule<>(HomeActivity.class,
                true,    // initialTouchMode
                false); // launchActivity. False to set intent.

@Before
public void initValidString() {
    // Specify a valid string.
    mStringToBetyped = "some_email@gmail.com";
    mNumberToBetyped = "12345678";
}

@Before
public void grantPermission() {
    getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                    + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
    getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                    + " android.permission.INTERNET");

}



@Test
public void inputText_sameActivity() {
    // Type text.
    onView(withId(R.id.txt_email))
            .perform(typeText(mStringToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.txt_pass))
            .perform(typeText(mNumberToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard());


    onView(withId(R.id.txt_email)).check(matches(withText(mStringToBetyped)));
    onView(withId(R.id.txt_pass)).check(matches(withText(mNumberToBetyped)));

    onView(withId(R.id.butn_login)).perform(click())

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need the intent to run so i can continue all the tests on a travis emulator. I've read not to test network requests but i dont mind waiting for as long as i can. I also read to swap out firebase with a local storage but i dont know how to do that. I need travis to run through the firebase code and log into the app on the emulator. I know I can start the intent manually but then ehat would be point of testing the loginAccount(). Help will be appreciated.